# Efficient methods/tools for managing a data warehouse pulling data from multiple database applications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse, integration

Until now I have used an on premise SQL Server 2012 and performed manual ETL operations to create/manage a data warehouse that contains data from multiple database application from different organizations.

I get the source data [several dozen csv/txt files some of them 50 MB in size] every month using 2 methods: 1) execute sql queries on the source databases (for the client-server applications) and 2) using a web-based reporting tool (for the web-based applications). The destination are databases in my SQL Server based data warehouse, which I manage using SSMS/SSIS. This manual process easily takes several hours each month to update the data warehouse. I now want to update the data on a more frequent basis (possibly daily) for better analytics/reporting. I suppose it would involve gaining direct access to the source database applications?

I need to get some high level information on the methods/tools out there to accomplish this and make this process efficient/automated.

Comment: I think there is no "best way". This depends on your situation. Since you can execute SQL queries, why not execute them more often. As far as I know SSIS can handle this. Combined with some kind of scheduling manager e.g. every day and error handling (writing to an extra table and checking for emptyness) this could be best-of-choice for you. Why do you think you might need direct access?

Comment: Given the characteristics of your data sources I would expect that SSIS would work very well for the source databases, and that using PowerShell would be a great way to go for the web-based applications.

Comment: Also keep in mind that doing this daily may well require less data anyway, so it would take less time.